# Issue uploading specific PDF documents within my Laravel CRM application

Tags: ajax, laravel

I was hoping someone could shine some light on a strange issue I have stumbled across recently within my Laravel CRM application. I am using MultiCRM + Laravel BAP to operate a small CRM system on my server.

The issue I am experiencing is that when I upload "specific" PDF documents through the CRM's AJAX file uploader, the file uploads and reaches the 100% stage and thereafter the following error is being returned:

> Unprocessable Entity

I have reviewed the error status/message within the Network tab of my Developer Console and I am seeing the following error:

> The given data was invalid - The files must be a type of Jpg, jpeg,
> png, pdf, txt, doc, docx

Some PDF's I can upload perfectly fine whereas other PDF's seem to be failing. I have checked the Properties of the file which I am attempting to upload and I can confirm that the file extension resembles the exact same of the PDF files which are uploading perfectly fine.

I have also reviewed the max_upload_size and `post_max_size` within my php.ini and I can confirm the values set in there are fine. I have tried to upload larger zip files 20mb+ to rule out any file upload size limits, and I can confirm that the zip files in question uploaded and saved perfectly fine.

I am just a little confused with why certain PDF files will upload and others won't.

If there any particular files which you should need to see, please let me know and i would be happy to provide the source code :-)

Comment: are those errored files with the good extention real pdf files ? The validator that failed the upload verifies the myme type of the file not the extention. if you take a  `.jpg` file and give it `.pdf` extention, it will still be a jpg file regarding its myme type.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head with this answer. :-) It was indeed because of the issue you described. I resaved the mischievous PDF as a new PDF document and the file uploaded perfectly fine! I would of never of thought of this as a solution so thank you! :-)